# Error: Duplicated files or mocks while amplifying add auth to my ReactNative Project

Tags: aws-amplify

mockPath1: 'amplify\#current-cloud-
backend\function\appf629d6ccf629d6ccPostConfirmation\src\package.json',
mockPath2: 'amplify\backend\function\appf629d6ccf629d6ccPostConfirmation\src\package.json'
}

Comment: I'll suggest you to elaborate a little on your question.  At least provide the steps you've done to setup amplify.